# Shoulda/Minitest redirect_to { url_helper } not working without hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, shoulda

Using Rails 4.2, Minitest, and Shoulda...

**student_phone_numbers_controller_test.rb**

```
class StudentPhoneNumbersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  context "deleting to remove" do
    context "when the phone number doesn't belong to the student" do
      setup do
        log_in_as(teachers(:schmidt))
        delete :remove,
          format: "js",
          student_id: students(:two).id,
          id: phone_numbers(:one_one).id
      end

      should use_before_action :logged_in_teacher
      should use_before_action :set_student
      should respond_with :redirect
      should redirect_to { student_path students(:two) }
    end
  end
end
```

New to Shoulda and Rails testing in general, and my code seems to parallel [the Minitest documentation for redirect_to](http://matchers.shoulda.io/docs/v3.0.0/Shoulda/Matchers/ActionController.html#redirect_to-instance_method). However, I'm banging into this error when running the test...

```
$ rake test:controllers
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

...pointing at the `should redirect_to` line. I assume it wants the controller/action hash?

The following line works as expected:

```
should redirect_to(controller: :students, action: :show) { student_url students(:two) }
```

...as does this...

```
should redirect_to({}) { student_url students(:two) }
```

The first fix is totally redundant. The second seems superfluous. I realize [the source for this method](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/action_controller/redirect_to_matcher.rb) doesn't have a default value for the single argument. Should it?

Or, am I missing something otherwise obviously about the purpose/workings of this helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a bug in the documentation and in fact was raised as an issue just recently: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/788. The first argument is meant to be a human-readable representation of the route; it's inserted into the name of the test and thus will show up in the output when you run the test.

So you might have something like:

```
should redirect_to("the URL for student two") { student_url students(:two) }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ahh... That's helpful! It appears in the source that the `&block` isn't mandatory. Is there a format I could be using in `url_or_description` that would allow me to do double-duty with one parameter? Just something that works with `assert_redirected_to`?

Comment: Unfortunately the block *is* mandatory here. You couldn't say `should redirect_to(student_url(students(:two)))` because `student_url` isn't available right away at the point where `should` is called -- it needs to be `instance_eval`'ed in the context of the test itself.

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much for taking the time to answer! :)